# how to execute sql script and save output in text file using python and sqlserver

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written this script in python which is reading a column from excel sheets and moving values into sqlserver table.

```
import pypyodbc as odbc
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r'd:\automate\2021062.xlsx',sheet_name =None)
mdf = pd.concat(df, axis=0, ignore_index=True)

columns = ['AXIO']
df_data = mdf[columns]
records = df_data.values.tolist()

DRIVER = 'SQL SERVER'
SERVER_NAME='PKKHICS01L3012\SQL2K12'
DATABASE_NAME='ATL'


def connection_string(driver, server_name, database_name):
    conn_string = f"""
        DRIVER={{{driver}}};
        SERVER={server_name};
        DATABASE={database_name};
        Trust_Connection=yes;        
    """
    return conn_string

try:
    conn = odbc.connect(connection_string(DRIVER, SERVER_NAME, DATABASE_NAME))
except odbc.DatabaseError as e:
    print('Database Error:')    
    print(str(e.value[1]))
except odbc.Error as e:
    print('Connection Error:')
    print(str(e.value[1]))


try:
    conn = odbc.connect(connection_string(DRIVER, SERVER_NAME, DATABASE_NAME))
except odbc.DatabaseError as e:
    print('Database Error:')    
    print(str(e.value[1]))
except odbc.Error as e:
    print('Connection Error:')
    print(str(e.value[1]))

sql_insert = '''
    INSERT INTO atlnew 
    VALUES (?)
'''

try:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.executemany(sql_insert, records)
    cursor.commit();    
except Exception as e:
    cursor.rollback()
    print(str(e[1]))
finally:
    print('Task is complete.')
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
```

now 2nd part is when the TASK IS COMPLETED i want to run some sql script on the table where data has been moved from excel and one executed want to save the output as text file so need guidance here. I wanted to paste the script but its not letting me so please bare with me.